# Yii2 ip based login

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to create a login with an username a password several roles and an ip verification, where when the user doesn't have an assigned ip he can't login. I'm saving my ip as a varchar in my user table and I'm trying to compare the ip on the table with the one of the user that's trying to login, but when I login it returns me this ip ::1 which is the ipv6 from localhost as I have read and in my db I have 127.0.0.1 (I have tried doing it with ::1 on the db but no success) my question is:

What should I do to get a correct response? here is my code

```
    public function validateIp($ip) {
    if($this->ip == Yii::$app->request->userIp)
    {
       return $this->ip == $ip;                   
    }
        else
        {
            $this->addError($ip, 'La IP no esta habilitada para este usuario');
        }
    
}
```

And here I execute the login

```
   public function login()  
   {
      if ($this->validateIp(Yii::$app->request->userIp)) 
      {
         if ($this->validate()) 
         {
           return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser());
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: IP addresses change a lot, you probably shouldn't rely on them for authentication.

Comment: Like Alexander said this is a bad idea, a lot of internet providers don't give households a static IP address. Stick to matching username and (hashed) password

Comment: an alternative to ip adress may be an extra check to a previously generated token. it could be stored at client side or sent via email. the built-in password recovery in advanced template may be a good example to follow in such case.

Comment: I'm doing it for a specific requirement, where the ips are static for each pc, the idea is to assign a pc for an user and that user can only login to the application form that specific pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rewriting the code i finally managed to succeed

```
//getting user ip
function conseguirIpUser()  
{  
    $ip = Yii::$app->request->userIp;
    return $ip;  
}  
    //Validate ip
    public function validarIp() {

    $ipUsuario= $this->getUser();

    if($this->conseguirIpUser() == $ipUsuario->ip){
        return true;
    }

}
```

and login call

```
    public function login()
{       
    #Si los datos son validos se realiza el login y se da un mensaje de bienvenida
    if ($this->validarIp()) {
       if ($this->validate()) {
           Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Bienvenido/a!');
           return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser());
       }
    }
    #en caso que la ip no sea valida para este usuario se regresara al index y se mostrara un mensaje de error

    if (!$this->validarIp()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Usted no esta autorizado para inicar sesión en este equipo');
        return $this->refresh();
    }
}
```